# How can I make a copy of list elements and preserve the original value in the list? python

Tags: python

```
my_list = [1, 2]
print my_list[0]
```

1

```
x = my_list[0]
x += 2
```

now 'x' equals 3 and my_list[0] also equals 3. How can I preserve my list elements so they remain unchanged?

Comment: Your code works as expected: the list in unchanged. The list would change if elements within it was mutable objects (like others lists for example). Then you should import and call `x = copy.copy(my_list[0])` to prevent changes to affect the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can slice it:

```
new_list = old_list[:]
```

or

```
import copy
new_list = copy.copy(old_list)
```

If this helped please voted up & marked “accepted”